# Java Shake Not Executing... why?

Tags: java, android, shake

Alright, I've fought with this for a week or so, but I'm confident that it's a simple fix. I'm new to Android development and am using a fair bit of shared code, so there is likely something I'm missing. This is a simple app that parse's news headlines from RealClearPolitics.com. It executes on a button just fine, so I know the parsing backend, and new text display are working fine. But when I try to use the same kind of set up for a shake, it doesn't work. I believe the issue is in the handshake between my MainActivity class and the ShakeEventListener, or how I'm executing the ShakeEventListener. I've followed online direction to the best I can, but am stuck. Any pointers? Here's my full code for reference sake, with suspected problem blocked by ------.

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.gregoriovasquez.rcpparse;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import static android.view.View.*;




public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener{

    Button button_name;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private ShakeEventListener mShakeEventListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //button properties
        button_name= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button_name.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);



        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
```

**----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            *// ShakeDetector initialization
            mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            mAccelerometer = mSensorManager
                    .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
            mShakeEventListener = new ShakeEventListener();
            mShakeEventListener.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeEventListener.OnShakeListener() {

```
            @Override
            public void onShake(int count) {
                handleShakeEvent(count)
        });*

    }

        public void handleShakeEvent(int count){
            TextView rootView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextView);
            rootView.setText(TextMatcher.PatternReturn());
        }
```

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            TextView rootView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextView);
            rootView.setText(TextMatcher.PatternReturn());

```
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mShakeEventListener, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mShakeEventListener);
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

ShakeEventListener:

```
package com.example.gregoriovasquez.rcpparse;

import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.util.FloatMath;

public class ShakeEventListener implements SensorEventListener {

    private static final float SHAKE_THRESHOLD_GRAVITY = 2.7F;
    private static final int SHAKE_SLOP_TIME_MS = 500;
    private static final int SHAKE_COUNT_RESET_TIME_MS = 3000;

    private OnShakeListener mListener;
    private long mShakeTimestamp;
    private int mShakeCount;

    public void setOnShakeListener(OnShakeListener listener) {
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnShakeListener {
        public void onShake(int count);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // ignore
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (mListener != null) {
            float x = event.values[0];
            float y = event.values[1];
            float z = event.values[2];

            float gX = x / SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
            float gY = y / SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
            float gZ = z / SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;

            // gForce will be close to 1 when there is no movement.
            float gForce = FloatMath.sqrt(gX * gX + gY * gY + gZ * gZ);

            if (gForce > SHAKE_THRESHOLD_GRAVITY) {
                final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                // ignore shake events close to each other
                if (mShakeTimestamp + SHAKE_SLOP_TIME_MS > now) {
                    return;
                }

                // reset the shake count after no shakes
                if (mShakeTimestamp + SHAKE_COUNT_RESET_TIME_MS < now) {
                    mShakeCount = 0;
                }

                mShakeTimestamp = now;
                mShakeCount++;

                mListener.onShake(mShakeCount);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Following in my Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />
```

Comment: Not sure what your requirements are, but you might be better off using a library for this: https://github.com/square/seismic

Comment: After a bit of work, I figured out how to add the library to my gradle. It worked like a charm. THANK YOU!!!